# Reading a string formatted like XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a string that is written out like an XML file. An example would look like this:

```
string = <Employees><EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>< ... ></Employees>
```

I am saving this in a table because I wanted to audit changes, but I didn't want to have multiple tables for different audits. This is because it would record changes to things other than employees. So using an XML style string in the database seemed like a good suggestion.

Now to the real business. I want to check to make sure that there were actually changes to the employee because one could go into the edit page, change nothing, and click save. As of right now, the data would write to the DB and just clutter it up with non-changed data.

I'd like to be able to check if the XML styled string that is going to be saved is on the database, so if `<employees><employeeid>###</employeeid> == "changes"` and then see if the whole string equals the other. Basically, check the `employeeId` first because that won't change, and then check the string as a whole to see if there is any difference. I would have just checked the first n numbers, but the id number could have a length of 1 to 3.

Also, because it is styled as XML, is there an easy way to convert it to read it like an XML file and check that way?

Comment: Yes use xml linq : XElement employee = XElement.Parse(string);

Comment: You can use C# classes to represent data of your xml. Compare changed properties with original ones and then serialize it to xml.

Answer (score 0):

Storing arbitrary data in a column is a form of denormalization. You can't really do much with it at a database level. However, SQL Server does have an `XML` column type. Entity Framework doesn't support mapping to/from an XML column, so it will simply treat your XML as a standard string. With this column type, though, you can write actual SQL queries against your XML using XPath expressions.

Your best bet, then, is to type your column as XML, and then write a stored procedure that performs the query you need. You can then utilize this stored procedure with Entity Framework.

For more information on the XML column type see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798(SQL.90).aspx